# Selenium Handle timeout driver.wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, wait

I'm using selenium-webdriver, waiting for a page to load and checking with `driver.wait` (waiting for a tag to show up).

**Two things**

1. Is there a way to handle the error from hitting the timeout on `driver.wait` (to stop it from crashing the server)?
2. And since I'm starting to suspect that approach is inappropriate, would this be a good place to just use `driver.sleep` and then use `driver.findElement` to check if the tag is present?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using promises, I found a solution to my problem:

```
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.tagName(selector)), 10 * 1000, "Timed out")
  .catch(function(e){
    if (e.message.match("Timed out")){
      return e; 
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  })
  .then(function(e){
    if (e.message && e.message.match("Timed out")){
      driver.quit();
    } else {
      [functional code]
      });
    }
  });
```

This is somewhat unwieldy, since selenium-webdriver just uses `throw error` instead of a named error on timeout. But it seems better than using `driver.sleep`.